# How to extract a number from a string

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Im a newbie in Apex and im developing a page using Visualforce.

My string format is always like this "xx-xx-999999". In this format I need to get only the integer. For example the string is  "RO-W1-445567". I want to get only the integer 445567 in the string. Can someone willing to share a piece of apex code in my problem.

Your help is vey much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Ferdie Banu

Comment: Maybe change the title to "Extract a number from a string". First I misunderstood that you want to bring a number into a string...

Comment: any answer, @uwe Heim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below

```
String formattedStr = 'xx-xx-999999';
String[] strArr = formattedStr.split('-');
Strnig strNumber = '';
Integer myNumber;

if(strArr.size() >2){
   strNumber = strArr[2];
   myNumber = Integer.valueOf(strNumber );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using regular expressions. You can replace all non number characters with empty character, and you will have only numbers left.
This regex says: any character a-z or A-Z or dash

```
String recordName = 'RO-W1-445567';
String regex = '[a-zA-Z]{1,}|\\-';
String recordNumber = recordName.replaceAll(regex, '');
System.debug(recordNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str ='RO-W1-445567'
String subStr =str.Substring(6,12);
Integer num=Integer.valueOf(subStr);
```

Comment: The indexes are wrong, you would need String str ='RO-W1-445567';
String subStr =str.Substring(6,12);
Integer num=Integer.valueOf(subStr);

Answer (score 0):

In case you have different pattern at the beginning of your string, you should always get everything after the last occurrence of the `-` symbol:

```
String yourString = 'RO-W1-445567';
Integer index = yourString.lastIndexOf('-');
String numberString = yourString.substring(index); // or index + 1 (I'm rushing :))
Integer theNumber = Integer.valueOf(numberString);
```