# get phone number from Field of type Phone without changing type to Text

Tags: apex

i have a Field of data type Phone. after querying from SOQL i am getting its value as (***) ***-**** in apex. How can i extract text value from it excluding hypen and (). I am looking for generic Phone to text type conversion.

Comment: Look here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42003/how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string

Comment: This is not duplicate since the reg ex based answer is what i was looking for. Other question of which this is marked as duplicate does not have as neat answer as this question has.

Comment: Its my bad, I put wrong url to look. Correct URL is http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45157/how-to-find-all-numbers-in-a-string-using-regex#answer-45159 . And answer you have here is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the solutions on here remove specific characters such as spaces and '-'.  If you just want to remove all non numbers and leave only the numbers, then try something like this.  this doesn't look at specific characters to remove, just removes all non numbers, so its a bit more flexible/scalable

```
string num = '(555) 555-5555';
system.debug(num.replaceAll('[^0-9]', ''));
```

When I look at my debug statement it simply leaves me with `55555555555`.

[image]